# What is the BNB decimal on BSC

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ether, bsc

I made a button to send 1BNB to another account by using Ether.js.

As I know, 1BNB has 8 decimals.

However, when I have to send 1 BNB to another, I need to put 1*10**18 which is 18 decimals

So, the code is

```
    const tx = await signer.sendTransaction({
        from: userAddr, 
        to:privateSale.address, 
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther('1')
        });
```

It can be clearly seen that I am sending 1 * 10^18, not 1 * 10^8 BNB.
However, 1*10^18 indicates 1BNB.

if 1*10^18 is really 1BNB, then 1 Jager(= 0.00000001 BNB) is 1 * 10^10?

Would someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BNB has 18 decimals on Binance Smart Chain (like other EVM native token) and 8 decimals on Binance Chain.

Based on your use of ethers, I’m guessing your interacting with BNB on BSC (and therefore use 18 decimals).

https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/cross-chain-transfer.html

Comment: And to add to the confusion, "Binance Chain" is merging with the "Binance Smart Chain" to be called the "BNB Chain" in 2022.